# how to create a virtual environment on python 3.2.

Tags: python, virtualenv

You may smile when read this question, but..
I read in many places how to do this work, but I have this trouble:

I use a windows 7 system; I already installed python 3.2 and the module virtualenv; when I put the instruction: 
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python 3.2
it send an syntax error. 
If I put the instruction:
/usr/bin/virtualenv-3.2 
It send the same syntax error. How do I create a virtualenv? Thanks for your help

Comment: How about a traceback? An error message? Literally any more information would help. We can't help you if we can't find out what the problem *actually* is.

Comment: ....I wasn't aware that `/usr/` existed on Windows 7. Actually, I'm pretty bloody sure it doesn't :P

Have you considered leaving out that argument and just running `virtualenv [name_of_virtual_environment]`?

Comment: Piggybacking off of @NightShadeQueen, maybe the problem is you're supposed to be doing this in a cygwin shell?

Comment: Just save yourself some trouble and don't do it in Windows. I know this is not a proper answer, but it wasn't a proper question either. Console things  don't work properly on Windows. They just don't. I worked with python for 8 years, and I'd be terrified to have to get anything working on Windows. Get virtualbox, install ubuntu or whatever, it's free and really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the path that you specify, which is unix based and not windows 7. Try to use the path to your python interpreter location on your windows system for the -p argument.

like for example:

```
mkvirtualenv -p c:/your/path/to/python2.5
```

May I give u some additional advice/tip:

In the past I've used virtualenvwrapper, which provides a set of function that make working with virtual environment a lot easier. I really loved it!

In order to install it, you should make sure that virtual environment is already installed, which I believe is the case for you.

Next run:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

next you can follow the simple steps [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#quick-start)

Comment: Note: `pip` is only included on Windows on [Python 2.7.9+ and Python 3.4+](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/1530134).

Comment: Since OP mentioned he installed 3.2, this won't be an issue I presume? I wasn't aware of this though, so thank you!

Comment: I tried this and works fine:    >set VENV=c:\myprojects    folowing: >c:\Python33\python -m venv %VENV% and voila..